# What is "I had be"?

Tags: word-meaning

> [image]
>
> Thirty of us went out after her. Four of us came back. **I'd be** out there with them, but after I lost my leg... I just couldn't ride anymore until I heel.

Is is just some sort of dialect of "had been"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this paraphrase:

> If it weren't for my having lost my leg, I **would** ***still*** **be** out there with them.

He was out there with them. He then lost his leg and was forced to leave. (No doubt to get medical treatment.)

It's clear that he *had* gone out there with them because of the context provided in the previous sentences:

> Thirty of us went out after her. Four of us came back.

The missing *still* is implied by this context.

---

It's just a different way of expressing a hypothetical conditional:

> I **would be** eating a steak right now, **but** after my boss insisted I work late, I wasn't able to leave the office (and so I'm still here and can't).

---

The quotation does have something ungrammatical, however:

> I just couldn't ride anymore until I heal.

(Note that the word should be *heal*, not *heel*.)

This should instead be expressed in one of two ways:

> I just **couldn't** ride anymore until I (had) **healed**.
>   I just **can't** ride anymore until I **heal**.

Answer (score 2):

In this case "I'd" is the short form of "I would",not "I had".

Comment: But then, it sounds to me like he didn't go there. But he actually went there and lost his leg. Could you give me some more examples with that kind of 'would'?

Comment: I think "would" refers to his intention to be there.

Comment: That's what I exactly thought at first. But my DVD translation interpreted that he went there only to lose his leg. So I looked up the wiki page of him, Cliegg Lars, but the page said something similar. I'm so confused now.

Comment: @dolco The sentences mean "I would be out there with them still [but my missing leg prevents me from doing this]. In other words, his physical handicap is preventing him from acting on his desire/intent to go back out. Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Remember ever, `I'd` is the short form of `I would`'.

Comment: I'm not trying to deny it is not "I would", but if I put "I would" there, I just can't understand the sentence at all. It baffles me that all sort of references about Starwars, at least I've found, says he 'was out there with them and lost his leg'. So then, "I would be out there" is same with "I was out there"? I couldn't find any dictionary entry for such uses. Could you give some examples with that kind of Would please?

Comment: @dolco The meaning, in other words, is "I would be out there (again) now, but I can't be because I lost a leg and that prevents me from being able to go out there again." Another example of this is: "I'd have dessert, but I ate too much dinner and am too full."